# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Toolkit for class: custom.SampleKeyword

Tags: selenium, groovy, katalon-studio

Uploading a file using robot class, but unable to upload it due to the exception.

```
@Keyword
def uploadFile(TestObject to, String filePath) {
    WebUI.click(to)
    StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(filePath);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

Calling this method in Tc, CustomKeywords.'custom.SampleKeyword.uploadFile'( findTestObject('Object'),'Path')

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing an `import` for `Toolkit`. Either add the following

```
import java.awt.Toolkit
```

or replace

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
```

with

```
java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
```

Comment: @snehajambula If you find the answer useful, please upvote and accept it (click up arrow and check mark next to the answer).